# refresh table without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a table that displays the contents of an array using knockoutjs. I want to be able to sort this table by clicking on the header of a column. My idea is to use javascript .sort() to sort the array, and then refresh the table without refreshing the page. I don't know how to refresh the table without refreshing the page. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be most appreciated!

Right now it is just an html table. Some cells contain if statements, others entire tables, and there are upwards of 80 records in the database. I don't want to make another ajax call, because nothing has changed in the database, just want to sort the array according to which header is clicked.

I added the onclick function but I'm getting the error that obj is not defined.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

aspx file:

```
<table id="filteredTable">
    <tr>
        <th><button class="btn btn-link btn sm" onclick="SortColumn('TicketTitle')">Title</button></th>
        <th>Priority</th>
    </tr>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: theObject[0]">
    <tr class="tableRow" data-bind="attr: { id: TicketId }">
        <td data-bind="text: TicketTitle"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: TicketPriority"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

js file:

```
function pageLoad() {
    var url = API_URL + "/api/Ticket/GetTickets";
    var data = Ajax.getData(url);
    var obj = [];
    var tickets = JSON.parse(data.JsonResult);
    obj.Tickets = tickets;
    Tickets.Data = obj;

    var viewModel = {
        theObject: [obj.Tickets]
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}

function SortColumn(column) {
    obj.Tickets.column.sort();
}
```

Comment: are you using a datatable or simple html table. If you can use a datatable and on that u can use fnDraw() this re-draw the table for you

Comment: If you  provide us code maybe a small help from you

Answer (score 0):

If your table shown the elements of the array (with the knockout's foreach function), you mustn't refresh table...

Sorting the array would sort the table...

But, if you want to simplify your life, i recommend to use the [DataTables plugin](https://www.datatables.net/)

With this plugin, you only draw your table in the DOM, and after that you apply datatables to the table you drew...

---

Hope this help.

Regards

---

#### Edit:

Try this (based on [@Jeroen solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419956/jeroen)):

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <!-- Calling a unnamed function to prevent auto-execute of the function 'changeSort' on binding -->
            <button data-bind="click: function() { resetDir('TicketTitle'); changeSort('TicketTitle'); }">Title</button>
        </th>
        <th>
            <!-- Calling a unnamed function to prevent auto-execute of the function 'changeSort' on binding -->
            <button data-bind="click: function() { resetDir('TicketPriority'); changeSort('TicketPriority'); }">Priority</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Tickets">
        <tr class="tableRow" data-bind="attr: { id: TicketId }">
            <td data-bind="text: TicketTitle"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: TicketPriority"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function ViewModel(obj) {
    var self = this;

    var sortDir = {
        TicketTitle: "DESC",
        TicketPriority: "DESC",
        LastPressed: ""
    };

    self.Tickets = ko.observableArray(obj.Tickets);

    self.resetDir = function(key) {
        if(sortDir['LastPressed'] != key) sortDir[key] = "DESC";
    }

    self.changeSort = function(newKey) {
        if(sortDir[newKey] == "ASC") sortDir[newKey] = "DESC";
        else sortDir[newKey] = "ASC";

        self.Tickets.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(sortDir[newKey] == "ASC") {
                if(a[newKey] < b[newKey]) return -1;
                if(a[newKey] > b[newKey]) return 1;
                return 0;
            } else {
                if(b[newKey] < a[newKey]) return -1;
                if(b[newKey] > a[newKey]) return 1;
                return 0;
            }
        });

        sortDir['LastPressed'] = newKey;
    };

    self.changeSort("TicketTitle");
}

function pageLoad() {
    // Fake data:
    var obj = {
        Tickets: [
            { TicketId: 1, TicketTitle: "Aaa title", TicketPriority: "C. Low" },
            { TicketId: 2, TicketTitle: "Be a title", TicketPriority: "B. Medium" },
            { TicketId: 3, TicketTitle: "Aaa title", TicketPriority: "A. High" },
            { TicketId: 4, TicketTitle: "Baahaha ya", TicketPriority: "A. High" },
            { TicketId: 5, TicketTitle: "C u later", TicketPriority: "B. Medium" }
        ]
    };

    var viewModel = new ViewModel(obj);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}

pageLoad();
```

#### Test the code in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xe3kfc6c/4/)

Comment: Wow I think you might be right, that is how knockout is supposed to work. I am going to try that right now.

Comment: I'm getting an error because I don't know how to pass the array to my SortColumn function

Comment: You mustn't pass your array as function parameter... You just need to sort the array that you created to populate the table...

Comment: Edit of above:

You mustn't pass your array as function parameter... You just need to sort the array that you created to populate the table... 

Lets say that your array is named `theObject`, you should do `theObject.sort()` inside your SortColumn function.

May be you should reference the array like this: `this.theObject.sort()`

Comment: The error was solved by putting the array in global scope. However when I click the table header the function doesn't work. The elements in the array are in a different order, but they are not in alphabetical order. And the order of the rows in the table hasn't changed at all.

Comment: I think the DataTables solution "sec" is a bad suggestion, as it'll get you into a fight with KnockoutJS. It *could* be made to work, but you'll need to provide some guidance as to how to integrate it with KnockoutJS. (Also: DataTables isn't a "light" choice, as it draws in a rather big dependency (jQuery) which OP hasn't tagged the question with.)

Comment: Well, in my case I decided not to use Knockout and whether to use DataTables in certain views, because I just needed not to sort by columns, but also needed to have a search filter, and DataTables made the task easier.
Sorry if it was not clear.
Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will be very similar to [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27018607/419956), with the advice to use a computed observable to represent the sorted table. For your scenario it might look like this:

```js
function ViewModel(obj) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.Tickets = ko.observableArray(obj.Tickets);
  
  self.sortKey = ko.observable("TicketTitle");
  
  self.changeSort = function(newKey) {
    // TODO: Handle asc/desc here too.
    self.sortKey(newKey);
  };
  
  self.TicketsSorted = ko.computed(function() {
    var key = self.sortKey();
    return self.Tickets().sort(function(a, b) {
      return a[key].localeCompare(b[key]);
    });
  });
}

function pageLoad() {
  // Fake data:
  var obj = { Tickets: [
    { TicketId: 1, TicketTitle: "Aaa title", TicketPriority: "C. Low" },
    { TicketId: 2, TicketTitle: "Be a title", TicketPriority: "B. Medium" },
    { TicketId: 3, TicketTitle: "Aaa title", TicketPriority: "A. High" },
    { TicketId: 4, TicketTitle: "Baahaha ya", TicketPriority: "A. High" },
    { TicketId: 5, TicketTitle: "C u later", TicketPriority: "B. Medium" }
  ] };

  var viewModel = new ViewModel(obj);

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}

pageLoad();
```

```css
td { padding: 2px 5px; background: #eee; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <button data-bind="click: changeSort('TicketTitle')">Title</button>
    </th>
    <th>
      <button data-bind="click: changeSort('TicketPriority')">Priority</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: TicketsSorted">
    <tr class="tableRow" data-bind="attr: { id: TicketId }">
      <td data-bind="text: TicketTitle"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: TicketPriority"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Wasn't sure how to stub the missing bits in your post (e.g. the data and how to retrieve it), so I just inserted some plain data there. (PS. Looks like your Ajax call is handled *synchronously*?)

Comment: I'd like to try this but don't know what to put in the TODO part. I want it to sort the Titles alphabetically.

Comment: Apart from the fact that the TODO isn't all to directly related to your specific question, if you don't know even where to start for that TODO I suggest going through some tutorials, e.g. [the ko tutorials are great](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), and getting back on SO once you have a specific problem.

Comment: (Although I now see that @SebastiánRodriguez [cut out some of the work for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36815142/419956) by remixing my code example with some sort-order magic.)

Answer (score -2):

In my opnion You can do something like this... but

```js
function refresh(){
var cont = "<table>"+
    "<tr>"+/*use  loop */
      "<td>"+
        "name"+
      "</td>"+
      "<td>"+
        "exe"+
      "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
    "<tr>"+
      "<td>"+
        "name2"+
      "<td>"+
        "exe2"+
      "</td>"+
      "</td>"+
    "</tr>"+
   "</table>";
  return cont;
}
document.getElementById("tableContainerID").innerHTML = refresh();
```

```html
<div id="tableContainerID"></div>
```

You can create a function and in  return give you all table data and call like function like this: `document.getElementById("tableContainerID").innerHTML = TableDataFunction();`

If you use jquery then maybe this can help you [.html();](http://api.jquery.com/html/)